# Why is my model.fit method is not working on tensorflow?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, sentiment-analysis, tf.keras

Currently I am trying to develop a multichannel CNN model for text classification. I am using the imdb dataset. I have vectorized the layer and transformed it into a tensor. The problem is that I don't know why the model fit method is not working.

The error message says:

> ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class
> 'list'> containing values of types {"<class
> 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset'>"}), <class
> 'NoneType'>

Code for creating a channel.

```
# channel 1
inputs1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(length,))
embedding1 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 100)(inputs1)
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(embedding1)
drop1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv1)
pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(drop1)
flat1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pool1)

# channel 2
inputs2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(length,))
embedding2 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 100)(inputs2)
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=6, activation='relu')(embedding2)
drop2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop2)
flat2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pool2)
# channel 3

inputs3 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(length,))
embedding3 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 100)(inputs3)
conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu')(embedding3)
drop3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv3)
pool3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop3)
flat3 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pool3)

# merge
merged = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([flat1, flat2, flat3])
print(type(merged))

# # interpretation
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(merged)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2, inputs3], outputs=outputs)
# compile
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# summarize
model.summary()

history = model.fit(
    [train_dataset,train_dataset,train_dataset],
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=16)
```

Please have a look at the google colab: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FywYG4zYo_Dx-3oQbU2Nc12Joy9ULcez#scrollTo=8BntrPWMUB9E)

Comment: Code has to be in the question as text, not as external links, we cannot access your code in colab.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy, I just added the important part of code. I also made possible that the code could be edited in the google colab